# R: view local variables

Tags: r

I would like to ask how function **h** can see variable **v1** defined in function **g**. Both h and g are defined in **f**. The solution I thought is to define the environment **e1** and to put there v1.
But this is not working, I get character(0) when I run ls(e1), and I do not know why.

```
e1 <- new.env()
f <- function(){
    g <- function(){
        e1$v1 <- 5
    }
    h <- function(){
        print(e1$v1)
    }
    h()
}
f()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually run the function `g()`. Try adding `g()` just before `h()`.

(Although, I feel compelled to add, for the benefit of folks finding this question in the future, that this sort thing, which works agains the natural scoping behavior of R is a dangerous things to play around with. So be careful!)